# Facebook marketing API to get campaigns active for particular day

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have script which pulls all campaigns from Facebook marketing API and then respective ads from it.

I have 200 campaigns. I need campaigns which were active on some past date say 12 Nov 2020. The campaign in inactive now, but was active on particular date. So when I query (using REST) for that particular date filtering by start and end date as 12 Nov 2020. It doesn't send me that campaign in results since campaign is not really active NOW.

Is there a way where I could get active campaigns on a particular date? or other way get only campaigns which really have some data on a given date?

Problem with loading all campaigns and then subsequent ads to check for data is huge problem due to throttling when we have good no of campaigns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to query with all the effective statuses in the filter object for the campaign. That will provide you with all the data you are after and not just the currently active.

Append the following filter to your graph api call for campaigns:

```
&filtering[]={"field":"effective_status","operator":"IN","value":["ACTIVE","PAUSED","DELETED","ARCHIVED","IN_PROCESS","WITH_ISSUES"]}
```